# Display div elements in one line

Tags: html, css

I have three elements in my div dropdown list, input date and button they are all in on div , i want all of them to be in the same line , not under each other

```html
<div id="cont">
  Status :
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
    <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
    <option value="Error">Error</option>
  </select>
  <!-- Date Picker -->
  <p>Date:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
  </p>
  <button type="submit" id="searchBtn" value="">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Comment: display : inline-block

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lge9qhkz/  Use inline-block

Comment: @MohamedNagy Then you're not using it right

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS with `display: inline-block`

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  Status:
  <select id="dropdown" class="inline">
    <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
    <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
    <option value="Error">Error</option>
  </select>
  <!-- Date Picker -->
  <p class="inline">Date:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
  </p>
  <button type="submit" id="searchBtn" value="" class="inline">Search</button>
</div>
```

Although the above works, it's better practice to put the specific elements in a `span` tag. Like so ...

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <span class="inline">Status:
    <select id="dropdown">
      <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
      <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
      <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
      <option value="Error">Error</option>
    </select>
  </span>
  <!-- Date Picker -->
  <span class="inline">
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
  </span>
  <span class="inline">
    <button type="submit" id="searchBtn" value="">Search</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `display: inline-block` property to the divs. This will make them get rendered inline with the content, but they keep their block properties, so you can still set their width and height for example.

Example:

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline" id="red"></div>
<div class="inline" id="blue"></div>
<div class="inline" id="green"></div>
```

My favourite tutorial site about the topic: http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html

This can be used for every element, which supports the `display` property. Some elements are even set to this by default, like the `span` element.

Comment: Don't use IDs for styling.

Comment: @JoeConsterdine If not IDs, then what should I use instead?

Comment: Use a class, ID cause specificity issues.

Comment: @JoeConsterdine I quickly gazed through Google to find a site that says the same as you do, but I couldn't. Most even says that you **should** use them if you want to refer to a single element

Comment: @JoeConsterdine There's a reason there's a different id and class property.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't be giving out front-end advice if you're having to google how to do stuff.

It's common knowledge using IDs is bad practise for styling.

This is from Harry Roberts, who's very well respected in the front-end community.

http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/when-using-ids-can-be-a-pain-in-the-class/

Comment: @JoeConsterdine 1.) I needed to google it, because I have never in my life heard about something so nonsensical. 2.) Because this doesn't have to do anything with my answer, I don't think I shouldn't give out advice, because of it 3.) When you want to insult someone, try actually looking stuff up before it "Don’t stop using IDs, just be aware of where they can cause you headaches and know where to sensibly circumvent them. Anyone telling you not to use them at all is not wrong, but they’re definitely not right…" Seriously, read the links you post

Comment: You do realise it was posted in 2011 and the top 2 lines are:

N.B. Since authoring this article I have decided that a blanket ban is sensible. Save yourself many potential headaches and never use IDs in your CSS files.

I have nothing else to say, carry on using IDs if you like.

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/v9qxobaf/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<style media="screen">
#cont {
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.status, .date, .button {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id="cont">

        <div class="status">
            <label>Status: </label>
            <select id="dropdown">
                <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
                <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
                <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                <option value="Error">Error</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="date">
            <!-- Date Picker -->
            <span> Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="button">
            <button type="submit" id="searchBtn" value="">Search</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day; teach him fishing and you feed him for a lifetime"

Comment: @Bálint I can't teach him CSS in a stackoverflow post. I've given him the solution. If he wants to learn CSS there's 10000+ tutorials out there to learn. He should be happy with the fish.

Comment: That still doesn't mean you should post a complete code without any comments/description about what changed.

Answer (score -2):

wrap each in a div and display: inline-block.